# Telegram bot - Updater

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-3.7, python-telegram-bot

This code is supposed to take up prices from 2 indexes from yahoo finance nd send them to the user when a text is sent in the chat:

```
import requests
import telegram
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_price(symbol):
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    price = soup.find("span", {"data-reactid": "14"}).get_text()
    return price

def check_price(update, context):
    symbols = ["^DJI", "^GSPC"]
    prices = [get_price(symbol) for symbol in symbols]
    message = "DJI: " + prices[0] + "\n" + "GSPC: " + prices[1]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=message)

token = "TOKEN NAME"
bot = telegram.Bot(token)

updater = telegram.Updater(token, use_context=True)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

price_handler = CommandHandler("price", check_price)

dispatcher.add_handler(price_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

`

However, it gives an error:

```
\stocks.py", line 21, in <module>
    updater = telegram.Updater(token, use_context=True)
AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'Updater'. Did you mean: 'Update'?
```

I have tried updating the telegram libruary and installing Updater, but it didn't work.

I have also tried other variations of the code:

```
import requests
import telegram
from telegram import Updater, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

def get_price(symbol):
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    text = page.text

    start = text.find("data-reactid=\"50\"") + len("data-reactid=\"50\"") + 1
    end = text.find("</span>", start)
    price = text[start:end].strip()

    return price

def main():
    token = "BOT_TOKEN_GOES_HERE"
    updater = Updater(token)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    
    def handle_text_message(update, context):
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        message = update.message.text

        dji_price = get_price("%5EDJI")
        sp_price = get_price("%5EGSPC")

        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f"DJI Price: {dji_price}\nSP Price: {sp_price}")

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_text_message))
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it gives a similar error due to Updater:

```
stocks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from telegram import Updater, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Updater' from 'telegram' (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no class `Updater` in the `telegram` package. There is [`telegram.Update`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/telegram.update.html) and there is [`telegram.ext.Updater`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/telegram.ext.updater.html) both of which have very litte to do with each other. The [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) explains this in more detail.

Please also note that you're using a version <= 13.15 of the `python-telegram-bot` libray. That version is no longer being supported. If you're new to `python-telegram-bot`, I recommend to get started with [v20](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: I have updated the python-telegram-bot, and currently have version 20.1. And for some reason that didn't help. I tried this as well:
`
token = Bot(token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
`
If this can help, here are my imports:
`
import requests
import telegram
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
`

Comment: But the problem in that line has changed.
The error now is:
```
line 11, in <module>
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
```

Comment: That's because the `Updater` class does not have an argument `use_context` in v20. Please refer to the link about v20 that I pointed you to.

Answer (score 0):

You should import updater from `exe` module.
`from telegram.exe import Updater`

Answer (score 0):

you have to import updater from telegram.ext

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
```